# docker-cloud how to bring your own node

Tags: docker-cloud

I am using windows machine(Docker Quickstart Terminal) for my Learnig/RnD
When I did this….
     19906@EBI222GFWWA MINGW64 ~
$ docker-cloud node byo

```
    curl -Ls https://get.cloud.docker.com/ | sudo -H sh -s d8144fbd91fa42e4a7d343cfb5c12a91
```

I got this output,
“Execute this command in your host and it will appear in the list of nodes automatically.”
Q: where to run this ? in my windows quick start terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Docker uses Linux lxc containers under the hood, unless I'm mistaken, meaning you could not natively use a Windows server. The quickstart terminal you mentioned is probably using some kind of virtual machine?

Furthermore, the Docker Cloud [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/tutorials/byoh/) indicates they only support *specific distributions* of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Docker quickstart terminal is a windows shell with the correct environment variables set to send docker commands to a virtual machine running Boot2Docker. Commands like curl and sudo will run locally on your windows machine, not on the boot2docker machine. Docker-Cloud doesn't support boot2docker either. You might use it to test-run docker images or docker compose scripts before committing your changes and letting docker-cloud deploy them to your nodes.

You can set up your own virtual machine using VirtualBox and a supported OS (below). Then run that command in your virtual machine.

Ubuntu - 14.04, 15.04

Debian 8

Centos 7

RedHat Linux 7

Fedora 21, 22